# Why is one class not able to recognize the public member variable of another class

Tags: vb.net, dll, dllimport

I have two classes as follows

```
    Public Class A_one     'This project does not have a dll generated even after a build. Any reason why ?
    Public Structure struct
        Dim xyz as String
        Dim p as String
    End Structure
    Public Sub xyz(...)
        ClassB_one_Obj = New ClassB_one_Obj(SampleStruct) 

        ClassB_one_Obj.send_struct(sampleStruct)   
    End Sub

    Public Class B_one       'In a different project 
    Public Sub send_struct(ByVal sampleStruct As A_one.struct)  'Throwing error here **"Type A_one.struct not defined"**
```

Can anybody explain why i'm getting the error. Is it because I have not added the dll reference of class A_one in Class B_one ?
I tried to add the reference dll of A_one , but was not able to find it either in the obj/bin folders .
Can anybody point me to a work around ?

**EDIT/UPDATE :** Figured that the class A_one which is the main executable creates objects of Class B_one and that is the reason we can't create an object of class A_one in B_one, since there is a deadlock-like situation.

Is it true that we can't create an object of the main class ( start-up class ) from another class ?

Comment: Could you please share the error which you are getting?

Comment: Classes do not get DLLs, only projects/assemblies.  Is this all in one project?

Comment: No.. The two classes are in separate projects.

Comment: The error is "Type A_one.struct not defined"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the error is because project B is not referencing project A, so it doesn't know anything about that type.

From withing Visual Studio, go to the properties of project B, References, Add. If project A is in the same solution as B, add it as as a Project/Solution reference, otherwise you can browse for the DLL. If you use the DLL method, you will have to ensure that the project type of project A is set to be a Class Library and that it has been successfully built. If its not set to be a Class Library project, it will most likely have built as an EXE file (you can add a reference to an EXE file as well, if you need project A to stay as a stand-alone executable).

Comment: Thanks  lot.. I'm gonna try that !

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. Still class B_one does not seem to be recognizing class A_one. I clicked on Add Reference and chose the exe file of Project having class A_one. Don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: @Sharat, when referencing a type in another project, your type name would look like `sampleStruct As ProjectA.A_one.struct`, the project name becomes part of the namespace, so its not just the class name.